# What is COUT doing with these integers?

Tags: c++, variables, integer

I'm using cplusplus.com and C++ Programming In Easy Steps by Mike McGrath to accomplish a lifelong goal of doing what you guys do all the time.

I'm understanding and learning, but I've reached a question I cannot seem to answer, and it is most likely because of the way I'm asking.

In the book, we have an example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

int main()
{
  float nums[3] ; // Declared then initialized.
  nums[0] = 1.5 ; nums[1] = 2.75 ; nums[2] = 3.25 ;

  // Declared and initialized.
  char name[5] = { 'm', 'i', 'k', 'e', '\0' } ;
  int coords[2] [3] = { { 1, 2, 3 } , { 4, 5, 6 } } ;

  cout << "nums[0]: " << nums[0] << endl ;
  cout << "nums[1]: " << nums[1] << endl ;
  cout << "nums[2]: " << nums[2] << endl ;
  cout << "name[0]: " << name[0] << endl ;
  cout << "Text string: " << name << endl ;
  cout << "coords[0][2]: " << coords[0][2] << endl ;
  cout << "coords[1][2]: " << coords[1][2] << endl ;

  return 0 ;
}
```

Now, I understand all the code used here, but what I don't understand is how the last two `cout`s work. So what we've done here, if I am understanding right, is define `coords` (co-ordinates) as int `coords[2] [3] = { { 1, 2, 3 } , { 4, 5, 6 } }` ;. Right. And now we're outputting data from it, right? Okay, so we say [0][2] and that, if added, would equal five. But 3 is the output.

So my first assumption was that `cout` must be instead multiplying the two ints. But then on the second one, we see that 1 and 2 are respectively 2 and 3, and when they are multiplied they equal six. So far so good. But then, I find, if I change 6 to 9, the output is ... 9. So, what's going on here? What is COUT doing here?

Comment: int coords[2] [3] is 2 rows with 3 columns. So coords[0][2] is 1st row  3rd column as index starts from 0

Comment: those are indices of the matrix, so you are just indexing to get the element you want. and all the best of luck on your lifetime goal :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not adding, and it's not multiplying - it's indexing. You have a two dimensional array, and element `2` of row `0` contains the number `3`.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you assume that `cout` has anything to do with arithmetic operations? It has not. It just outputs values. For `coords[0][2]`, that is the third (**2**+1) element in the first (**0**+1) array. Which is 3.

Observe this:

```
int x = coords[0][2];
cout << x << endl;
```

It will print the same thing.

By the way, I hope you realise that `std::vector` and `std::string` are the first tools of choice in C++, not arrays.

Comment: I was trying to understand what the calling of two things was all about. I was looking at it from the wrong angle. My apologies.

Comment: No need to apologise for asking a question!

Answer (score 2):

```
int coords[2] [3] = { { 1, 2, 3 } , { 4, 5, 6 } } ;
```

Defines a multi-dimensional array, much like a matrix with 2 rows & 3 columns.

```
cout << "coords[0][2]: " << coords[0][2] << endl ;
```

Above line is printing the value in 1st row & 3rd column [C/C++ are zero index based languages]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `cout` is not doing anything to the numbers other than displaying them as strings.

Secondly, the `[`*`]` does not change the numbers. Rather it refers to a position in an array. For example, `char k = name[2];` looks at the second character in the array `name`, and is equivalent to `char k = *(name + 2);`. For a two-dimensional array, `int value = coords[2][1]` refers to the first element in the first layer of `coords`. This is equivalent to `int value = *(coords + ((2 * WIDTH) + 1));`. A three-dimensional array follows the trend, where `float x = cubemap[8][11][3];` would be equivalent to `float x = *(cubemap + (((8 * (WIDTH * HEIGHT)) + (11 * WIDTH)) + 3));`. None of these affect the actual values in the array, instead these index numbers are exactly that, specifying positions.